# Why can't I specify criteria for a conditional query as a form component?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two drop downs, Combo_A and Combo_B.
I'm attempting to achieve a "cascading combo box" or "synchronous combo box" where a selection from Combo A (say, a US State) would populate Combo B (say a particular list of cities which belong to said state).

I understand using the VBA code to do this, and the reason you'd prefer to use VBA, but my question is WHY must I use VBA.

Simply making a conditional query with criteria of:

> [Forms]![Main_Form]![State_Dropdown]

Doesn't seem to work.
There IS a requery (of the City_Dropdown) performed AfterUpdate (of the State_Dropdown).
Then I'm asked to provide the values for

> `Form!Main_Form!State_Dropdown`

...after manipulating the State_Dropdown.

Why doesn't this work intuitively?
Security?
Function?

Comment: It DOES work intuitively like I said, and also like the answer provided.
Somewhere deep down in my form there's a setting checked that keeps bugging out. I couldn't find it, replicated a whole new form and it works like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the controls are on same form, don't need to reference the Forms collection and form name. In ComboB RowSource:
`SELECT [City] FROM [Cities] WHERE [State]=[ComboA];`

I recommend the requery code be in ComboB GotFocus event.

Be aware cascading comboboxes don't work nice with continuous or datasheet form if ComboB RowSource includes lookup alias.