# MS Access - Subform behavior change

Tags: ms-access

In this database I have 9 tables, 7 lookup tables and two transactional tables; new_app and new_item.  New_item is on the many side of the one-to-many relationship.  I have two forms based off of the two tables titled newapp and newitem.  Newitem is a subform to newapp.  I also have two tables titled EmpName and EMail.  On the newitem form I have two combo boxes tied to the EmpName and EMail tables.  I want the selection in the EmpName combo box to limit the selections available in the EMail combo box.  When I open the newitem form by itself, the combo boxes work just fine.  When I open the newapp form, which has newitem as its subform I get the error message dialog "Enter Parameter Value - Forms!newitem!cmb_Rec_Name".
I'm unclear as to why the combo box lookup functionality works when the newitem form is open as a single form, but fails when the newitem is opened as a subform to the newapp form.

This is probably something simple.  Please let me know if I need to provide more information.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't work because the subform is not open as an independent object. Review the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220213/why-cant-i-specify-criteria-for-a-conditional-query-as-a-form-component/43220950#43220950

Comment: Thank you.  This fixed the probem, appreciate the help.  Thanks again.